# Visual Studio 2015 output window missing

Tags: visual-studio-2015

The output window that shows all the build messages in Visual studio is missing. I was not able to bring it back using the view menu.
I tried safe mode and diagnostic mode, and restarted everything.

How can I get the window back?

Answer (score 9):

To quote [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hk6fby3.aspx):

> The Output window does not appear on the View menu in Visual Studio Express editions. To bring it up, use the hotkey CTRL + ALT + O.

Comment: You need to close all solutions, exit, start with no solutions, then this works. Per ikku100 below.

Answer (score 5):

Launch the following:

```
devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem but found out that if you open visual studio without a solution, and then press ctrl-alt-o a couple of times, you get the output window back! Then you can open your original solution and get it all sorted.

Definitely a bug in visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 2):

It is apparently a bug in VC++ 15 as well as in VC++ 17. There are a few ways to re-produce this bug.
To get your missing window back, Go to Window -> Reset Window layout, all your disappeared windows will come back again.

Comment: It worked but the Output window has no name now (the tab is blank). But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and tried all of your solutions without success.  Then, finally, I just tried closing every single window I could and discovered that the output window was hidden behind another docked window.  There were no tabs or anything. Seems like a bug with Visual Studio (or at least terrible UI).

Answer (score 1):

For me it was enough to **close Visual Studio** and re-open it again.

Answer (score 1):

### **Short Answer:**

For Mac try using Spectacle or another 3rd party window manager.

### **Explanation:**

Was having this issue June '20 on Visual Studio Community 2019

I had made output a separate window and it spawned out of range and even going in to expo mode (show all windows in mac, 4 finger swip up IIRC) didn't show it.

I could see it in the window drop down menu, and move to it using cmd + ~ but wasn't able to bring it back until I tried Spectacle.

Restarting VS didn't work but luckily I found this thread when trying to find keyboard shortcuts to move windows

https://superuser.com/questions/68811/what-keyboard-shortcuts-move-resize-and-maximize-windows-under-mac-os-x?newreg=395b6a955557441da52b8592306c5c83

Selected the window then hit the keyboard shortcut to have it display on one side of the screen and viola!

Answer (score 0):

Go to View Menu > Select Output